# Counting how many times a character is typed without using string

Tags: c

I'm trying to find a way to count the amount of times the user types the letter `'c'` (uppercase or lowercase) without using strings. Certain user inputs such as `cvcc` leads to the programming printing that `'c'` was only entered 2 times.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;

    printf("Enter a string:");

    do
    {
        if ((getchar() == 'c') || (getchar() == 'C'))
        {
             counter++;
        }
    } while (getchar() != '\n');

    printf("The letter c was entered %d times\n", counter);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ((getchar() == 'c') || (getchar() == 'C'))
```

You are reading two different characters if the first is not `'c'`. Read the character once and then compare with both characters.

```
 int input = getchar();
 if (input == 'c' || input == 'C')
 {
     //do something
 }
```

Always worry about EOF.  Note that `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

```
 do
{
    int input=getchar();
    if ((input == 'c') || (input == 'C'))
    {
         counter++;
    }
} while (input != '\n');
```

Comment: The program still fails to correctly count the amount of times c is entered, an example is if the user entered cvcc, the program prints c was entered 2 times.

Comment: @Ludwig  That's because the `while` also contains a `getchar`. You can only have one `getchar` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the input variable in while loop, instead use the following logic.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int counter=0;
while(1)
{
    int input=getchar();
    if(input=='c'|| input=='C')counter++;
    else if(input=='\n')break;
}
printf("%d",counter);
}
```

You will get the desired output.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not add duplicate answers. A very similar answer has been already posted and accepted.

Comment: @Narendra, As Ludwig had mentioned that the program still fails to print the required output, so i tried it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int ch;

    printf("Enter a string: ");

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
        if (ch == 'c' || ch == 'C')
            counter++;
    }

    printf("The letter c was entered %d times.\n", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

The main change is that `getchar` is only called once per iteration and saved in a variable. After that, you can access the variable value as often as you want without any side-effects. Calling `getchar` multiple times reads a new character each time.

I also added a check for `EOF` just in case the user presses `Ctrl+D` or `Ctrl+Z` and thereby finishes the input. Your original program would end up in an endless loop.